# effect of developer unlocking on windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I know this is a very basic question but I really want to know if regularly testing your app on windows phone  8 developer unlocked device adversely affects the device performance and working or in some manner can affect device?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this on 3 separate phones and I've never noticed any difference!

Answer (score 0):

If your apps are all well behaved and you don't reach the limit of 10 such apps installed on your phone then the answer is no. If you do have 10 such well behaved apps installed then you will not be able to test more apps until you uninstall one of the previous apps.

If your apps are badly behaved with memory leaks, battery hogging etc. then of course they will adversely affect your phone until you uninstall them.

If you develop very large apps which use large amounts of storage then you may run out of storage on your phone until you uninstall them.

If you are trying to develop some kind of phone app virus and you succeed then again installing (which will happen automatically if you test on the device) will install the virus on your phone. Hopefully such an app would fail MS certification.